# SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled not available in SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, project-templates, save-as-template

I want to create site-templates in SharePoint 2013 online. Even by deactivating the publishing features, the save as template option didn´t pop up.

Now i found this tutorial how to activate the option in SharePoint: [workaround](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/05/03/missing-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/)

The problem that i have now, is that the "SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled" parameter in the site options doesn´t exists.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Refer this link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0887cfe8-62a4-4eff-8d1b-9305f4a2c0ce/save-site-as-template-missing-sp2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 5):

**You should be aware of the following points:**

- Once the publishing feature is activated the ‘`Save site as a template`‘ option will be unavailable below Site Action.
- Deactivate publishing features will not show back the ‘Save site as a template‘ option.
- You’ll not be able to ‘Save site as a template‘ by any means.
- Any **workaround on the internet** to ‘Save site as a template‘ from Publishing Site or from a site that has ever had publishing features enabled is unsupported and often (99.9999999%) doesn’t work.

So Missing `Save site as a template` = `SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled` is a normal behaviour regardless you deactivated Publishing Feature or not.

Read more at [MISSING SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Answer (score -2):

It also does not work if you have any apps or add-ins installed!

You need to enable the SaveSiteEnabled Options from the SharePoint designer.

IF even the SharePoint designer does not show that option, you have to Enable the Custom Scripting feature in SharePoint > Admin > Settings section. Yes, also as I said that having apps on your site will prevent you creating a subsite.

Comment: Why a downvote for me I could not understand! Thats a true reason! <br> you can also try opening the page directly. https://spsite/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx . The savetmpl.aspx url really helps.